# Promise is not working while forming an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js, express

iam trying to form an array of resulting an object using "Promise" in my server side but the array is not printing after the total objects were pushed to that array it is showing an empty array

### here is my code

```
 var Promise = require('bluebird'),
         hh = require('http-https')
         mongoose = require('mongoose'),
         collection = mongoose.model('Collection');


    function getInValidImgUrl(prodObj){

 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    hh.get(prodObj.imageUrl, function (res) {
      if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        /*  console.log("IN HHHHH : " + res.statusCode);*/
        resolve({
          type: 'success',
          ImgUrl: prodObj.imageUrl
        })
      }

    }).on('error', function (e) {
      // console.error(e);
      resolve({
        type: 'error',
        ImgUrl: prodObj.imageUrl
      })
    });
  })

    };


    exports.sampleFunc=function(){
    collection.find({category:"electronics"}).exec(function(err,products){
     if(err){
      console.log(err)
      }else{
        var imgArr=[];
//eg:products=[{name:"mobile",imageUrl:"http://somepic.jpg"}]

       for(var i=0; i<products.length: i++){
           var calback = getInValidImgUrl(products(i));
            calback.then(function(result){
               imgArr.push(result);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(imgArr)); // In this it showing every object is pushing into imgArr
             })
        }

       Promise.all(imgArr).then(results =>{
          console.log("IAMGE ARRAY :"+JSON.stringify(results)); //here iam not getting array it is showing an empty array
        })

      }
    });
    }
```

may i know where i did a mistake and why it is not printing the total array.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: What is expected result of condition at `if (res.statusCode !== 200) {}` ? Do you not want to call `resolve()` if `res.statusCode` is not equal to `200`?

Comment: iam trying to get which are having `statusCode!=200` means i want the remaining all products which statusCode are not having 202 @guest271314

Comment: `200` is different than `202`, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getInValidImgUrl` is asynchronous.Your `imgArr` is filled in the callback after result is returned.

Your `promise.all` is getting executed before all the previous promises of http requests are returned.

Check [here for Promise.all docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Try:

```
var calback=[];
 for(var i=0; i<products.length: i++){
           calback[i] = getInValidImgUrl(products(i));
        }
 Promise.all(calback).then(results =>{
          console.log("IAMGE ARRAY :"+JSON.stringify(results)); 
        })
```

[A sample js fiddle to show Promise.all](https://jsfiddle.net/0utu41qu/)

Comment: iam getting only one object in that array remaining are not pushing into that array @Suraj Rao

Comment: put a catch after then in Promise.all and check if you are getting any errors

Comment: iam not getting any error, what iam saying is while in the process of assinging the value to `calback[i]` from `getInValidImgUrl`function it is pushing only one value to the array so that it is printing only one object @Suraj Rao

Comment: all the status is coming good, i changed `Promise.all` to `Promise.each` to whether even one object is printing (or) not, it showing one object when i used `Promise.all` the console is not printing @Suraj Rao

Comment: may not be related but `on('error', function (e) {
      // console.error(e);
      resolve({
        type: 'error',
        ImgUrl: prodObj.imageUrl
      })
    })` should be reject...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131951/discussion-between-midhunsai-and-suraj-rao).